# Weird focus/selection behavior in Firefox on input and text areas when editing questions

Tags: bug, edits

I have recently started to notice there is something weird about the focus and selection behavior of the input fields (and text area) of a question. I'm not entirely sure when it started, but I think it has been a few weeks at most, maybe since the Teams related style changes.

When you edit a question, and want to select something from an input field that doesn't have the focus, then you can't select text immediately: on click+hold and mouse move, the field will receive focus, but no text gets selected. You first need to click to give focus, and then click+hold and move the mouse to select text.

I have this problem on Firefox Quantum 62.0b13 (64-bit) (beta channel) on Windows 10. <s>As this is a Firefox beta, it might also be a problem in Firefox</s> (reproduced on Firefox 61.0.1 (release channel) by Peter Mortensen).

I also checked in Chrome (68.0.3440.84), and that doesn't exhibit this problem.

Steps to reproduce:

1. Open a question and edit it

   **Result**: the body field has the focus
2. Try to select something in the title: click+hold and move the mouse to select

   **Result**: the title field receives the focus, but nothing is selected
   **Expected**: the title field receives the focus and text is selected
3. Try again to select something in the title: click+hold and move the mouse to select

   **Result**: Text in the title is now selected
4. Try to select something in the body: click+hold and move the mouse to select

   **Result**: the body field receives the focus, but nothing is selected
   **Expected**: the body field receives the focus and text is selected
5. Try again to select something in the body: click+hold and move the mouse to select

   **Result**: text in the body is now selected

Comment: I can confirm the problem on Firefox 61.0.1 (claimed to be up to date).

Comment: @PeterMortensen Thanks, I've made a note of it in the question

Comment: Yes, I noticed this on Firefox Nightly 63.0a1 as well. I’m not sure whether this is SO-specific or `contenteditable`-specific.

Comment: Repro on Waterfox 56

Comment: Cross-site post on Meta.SE: [Can't select the text without first clicking and focussing the text field](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/328370/289905).

Comment: This appears to be fixed in Firefox Nightly 88.0a1.